# Error C3867: Functional call missing argument

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, com

I get the following error:

Error   1   error C3867: 'CHelloproxy::Hello': function call missing argument list; use '&CHelloproxy::Hello' to create a pointer to member c:\users\uma\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\nproject\nproject\Helloproxy.h   24  Nproject

```
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
        __uuidof(Hello),            // Request Hello object
        NULL,                   // This is not an aggregate
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,   // COM object in client’s address space
        __uuidof(IHello),             // Request IHello interface pointer
        (void **) &pIHello);
```

Comment: Did you try `__uuidof(CHelloproxy)`?

Comment: No.  It must be __uuidof(Hello)

Comment: The compiler thinks you are trying to form a pointer-to-member to CHelloproxy::Hello, a function. Are you possibly doing this inside some CHelloproxy method, and you need to scope the Hello identifier to refer to something outside the class? Your comment says you want a Hello object.

Comment: I have two Hello functions.  One is CHelloproxy::Hello and the other one is imported from another dll file.  I am invoking the dll's Hello function from the CHelloproxy::Hello function.  Am I clear?

Comment: The problem is mine.  I have both the COMClass name and function name same as "Hello".  Hence, the compiler recognises the COMClass name as the function name.  I changed the function name.  Now everything works fine.......  Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Compiler docs say:
"You tried to take the address of a member function without qualifying the member function with its class name and the address-of operator."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0x1aatf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Are you passing the name of a member function as a parameter accidentally?